# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle custom registration field

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have default FOSUserBundle registration form. I want to add "jabber" field into registration form, which is optional (not required to fill).

User entity:

```
protected $jabber;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="100")
 */
```

But when i try it, i can't register witout filling "jabber" field. How can i make it unnecessary, to fill that field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to mark it as nullable:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="100", nullable="true")
 */
protected $jabber;
```